# Enter a number of employees or select from a range?

Tags: forms

In a form asking the user about the number of employees at their company, is it better to ask the user to enter a number or select a range?

Comment: Do you mean ask them "1-25, 26-50, 51-100" etc? or are you talking about the type of UI control you should use (i.e. slider)?

Comment: A critical question: what will you do with the number if you get the exact number (e.g. 8322, 137, 10110)? Will you use it as is, or will you filter the result again?

Comment: This totally depends on what you need the data for. If you *need* a specific number then you can only ask for that to be entered. So, why do you need to know this figure?

Comment: How many people know exactly how many employees their company has?

Answer (score 11):

**Use a tried-and-tested list of ranges.**

Many employees, especially of larger companies, simply don't know many other people work for the company. (I don't know exactly how many colleagues I have, as they're spread across 8 international offices)

If you force them to input a specific number, you create what will be for most people a negative experience resulting in them just making something up.

**LinkedIn publish a readily-usable list of values**

The developers at LinkedIn, who presumbably have put some thought into this, make a list available for third party developers.

Use something like this.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/reference/company-size-codes#

- Self-employed
- 1-10 employees
- 11-50 employees
- 51-200 employees
- 201-500 employees
- 501-1000 employees
- 1001-5000 employees
- 5001-10,000 employees
- 10,001+ employees

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using both in a single row. First would be text input with type 'Number' (for contextual keyboard) and another would be predefined number range as type 'Select'.

This way you would increase the horizon for a user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest entering the number manually as this will enable user to save time and also provide you with more accurate data.